# How to create Gitlab CI rules that are evaluated as AND instead of OR

Tags: gitlab-ci

The following gitlab ci job will run if the variable $CI_COMMIT_TAG is set **OR** if the ./versions.txt file has changed.

```
some-job:
  script:
    - echo "Do some fancy stuff.";
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: always
    - changes:
      - ./versions.txt
```

However, what I need is for this job to run when $CI_COMMIT_TAG is set **AND** ./versions.txt is changed. I don't want the job to run if only one of these evaluates to true. This was the behaviour in only/changes feature, but the only (and except)-feature is less powerful and deprecated.

Is what I want currently possible with gitlab ci?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#complex-rule-clauses):

In the following example:

We run the job manually if Dockerfile or any file in docker/scripts/ has changed **AND** $VAR == "string value". Otherwise, the job will not be included in the pipeline.

```
docker build:
      script: docker build -t my-image:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG .
      rules:
        - if: '$VAR == "string value"'
          changes: # Will include the job and set to when:manual if any of the follow paths match a modified file.
          - Dockerfile
          - docker/scripts/*
          when: manual
```

Your code will look something like this.

```
some-job:
  script:
    - echo "Do some fancy stuff.";
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      changes: 
        - versions.txt
      when: manual
```